# user defined function to register variables as global

Tags: php

```
function registerglobal() {

    $args = func_get_args();

    while (list(,$key) = each ($args)) {

        if (isset($_GET[$key])) $value = $_GET[$key];
        if (isset($_POST[$key])) $value = $_POST[$key];
        if (isset($_FILES[$key])) $value = $_FILES[$key];

        if (isset($value)) {

            if (!ini_get ('magic_quotes_gpc')) {

                if (!is_array($value))
                    $value = addslashes($value);
                else
                    $value = slasharray($value);
            }

            $GLOBALS[$key] = $value;
            unset($value);
        }
    }
}
```

i am a beginner in php and found this function, can any one help me in understanding this one. this has been declared in function.php and has been called in the top of index.php and gives error of undefined variable in the following line of

> draw_inputfield('password','','password','class="txtbx"');?>

Comment: I think that this is a pretty old function , as you are a beginner in PHP try to learn the most recent changes , read updated articles, browse new libraries that does not contain such a old code.

Comment: thanks for your reply, can you specify one site or tutorial on login and session to start with

Comment: google.com will be the greatest start for you, however I would recommend Modern PHP: New Features and Good Practices book, or phptherightway.com